# Comparing Dates in vba

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I am having an issue comparing Dates in excel. One date values is pulled from a worksheet and is in the form "24-JAN-17". The other data is declared in the script in from "2017-12-31". Does anyone know a solution to comparing the two dates so I can determine if the date value pulled from the sheet is later than 2018. I have included the code in it's current state below.

```
Sub removeWrongYear()

Dim i As Long, yearA As Long, rowsCnt As Long
Dim rowsToDelete As Range
Dim vData As Variant

yearA = 2017

With ActiveSheet

    '1st to 635475 row, 20th column
    vData = Range(.Cells(1, 20), .Cells(635475, 20))

    For i = UBound(vData) To 2 Step -1
        If vData(i, 1) > DateSerial(yearA, 12, 31) Then
            rowsCnt = rowsCnt + 1

            If rowsCnt > 1 Then
                Set rowsToDelete = Union(rowsToDelete, .Rows(i))
            ElseIf rowsCnt = 1 Then
                Set rowsToDelete = .Rows(i)
            End If

        End If
    Next i

End With

If rowsCnt > 0 Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rowsToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have all the 635475 rows with data?

Comment: What's the issue you're having? Explain please. Does your `vData` array actually contain *dates*, or is it date-like strings?

Comment: `If (Year(dateValue) > 2017) Then ... `

Comment: @DavidZemens I am trying your suggestions right now, do you know how much this will increase the run time of the script?

Comment: I don't know, but my guess is that it won't.  comparing to a constant rather than evaluating the DateSerial function should be faster. but tbh it's probably negligible. in any case that seems like an odd question to ask, because you can easily test it yourself and find out the answer :)

Comment: in your code, implement like `If Year(vData(i, 1)) > yearA`

Comment: @DavidZemens I am having an issue now where Year(vData(i, 1)) is taking the first numbers of the date 22-JAN-18  instead of the 18. Do you know what could eb causing this.

Comment: Yes I have some ideas can you add a screenshot of the dates? Can you also confirm whether the values are string-literals or date values?

Comment: @DavidZemens I have included a screenshot showing the data I am using. As for the values the data is string text.

Comment: ok so it's definitely a locale issue. I'm not 100% sure of resolution because I won't be able to replicate the error on my (US locale) computer.  but I can probably walk you through it.  first: what does the cell warning indicate? (the green flag in the cell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with string literal values on the worksheet, which represent dates in a US date format (DD-MMM-YY). These are *not `Date` values*, they're just strings. So when you try to parse it like a string like "22-JAN-18" e.g. using the `Year` function, my understanding is that it *should* return "2018". But working with different locale settings can be tricky, and this is complicated by the fact that VBA -- despite locale settings -- always (?) interprets dates in US format.

Can you test this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim s as String
    s = "22-JAN-18"
    Debug.Print Year(s)

End Sub
```

If that's not working, try:

```
Debug.Print Year(Format(s, "DD-MMM-YY"))
```

That may work, because you're explicitly specifying the *format* of the date-like string.

If that works, then try:

```
Dim theDate as Date
theDate = DateValue(Format(vData(i, 1), "DD-MMM-YY"))

If Year(theDate) > yearA Then 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

*One date values is pulled from a worksheet and is in the form "24-JAN-17". The other data is declared in the script in from "2017-12-31".*

To compare two variables, the best way is to make sure that they are of the same type. Thus, try to parse them as dates. Then compare:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim dt1 As Date: dt1 = "24-JAN-17"
    Dim dt2 As Date: dt2 = "2017-12-31"

    Debug.Print Year(dt1) < 2017
    Debug.Print Year(dt1)

End Sub
```

In your code `> DateSerial(2016, 12, 31)` is pretty much the same as `Year(dt1) < 2017`, but taking the year seems a bit easier.

Comment: You're trying to assign a `String` value to `Date` type variable, it will produce "Type mismatch".

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk - the type mismatch will be only if it cannot be parsed to a date. And this error is a good one, it means that the input should be checked.